# Android Sort custom listview with image and text

Tags: android, listview, sorting

I want to create a listview with image and text that is sortable. I'm done creating the custom listview with image and text. Note that the values of the texts come from my database. Also I'm done with sorting the text but I can't sort the position of image.

Can you give me some considerations to achieve the sorting of both text and image? So far this is what I have tried:

```
 static int[] imgs = {
        R.drawable.dinaretreat, // 0
        R.drawable.cobterrace, // 1
        R.drawable.ventassostreet, // 2
        R.drawable.summerhillblvddrouin, // 3
        R.drawable.todmanstreetdrouin
};
String[] text, loc, price;

private DBHelper dbHelper;

MyCustomAdapter adapter;

 // TODO displayRecords
private void displayRecords() {

    checkDatabaseConnection();

    text = dbHelper.getAll();
    price = dbHelper.getAllPrices();
    loc = dbHelper.getAllLocations();

    adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(imgs, text, loc, price);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

}

class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    String[] data_tvName;
    String[] data_tvLocation;
    String[] data_tvPrice;
    int[] data_image;

MyCustomAdapter() {
    data_tvName = null;
    data_tvLocation = null;
    data_tvPrice = null;
    data_image = null;
}

MyCustomAdapter(int[] image, String[] house, String[] location, String[] price) {
    data_tvName = house;
    data_tvLocation = location;
    data_tvPrice = price;
    data_image = image;
}

public int getCount() {
    return data_tvName.length;
}

public String getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View row;

    row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow, null);

    textview1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    textview2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvLocation);
    textview3 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
    ImageView imageview = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image);

    imageview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    textview1.setText(data_tvName[position]);
    Spanned strFormattedLocation = Html.fromHtml("<b>Location: </b>");
    Spanned strFormattedPrice = Html.fromHtml("<b>Price: </b>");
    textview2.setText(strFormattedLocation + data_tvLocation[position]);
    String strPrice = strFormattedPrice + "$" + (new DecimalFormat("#,###.00")).format(Integer.parseInt(data_tvPrice[position])) ;
    textview3.setText(strPrice);
    imageview.setImageResource(data_image[position]);

    return (row);

    }
}
```

**DBHelper.class**

```
 public String[] sortLocationAsc(){
            Cursor localCursor =  
                   this.myDataBase.query(DB_TABLE, new String[] { 
                       KEY_ID, KEY_HOUSE, KEY_PRICE, KEY_LOCATION }, 
                       null, null, null, null, 
                      KEY_LOCATION + " ASC");
            String[] array = new String[localCursor.getCount()];
            int i = 0;
            while(localCursor.moveToNext()){
                String uname = localCursor.getString(localCursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_LOCATION));
                array[i] = uname;
                i++;
            }
            return array;
        }
```

I don't know what's wrong with this or have I forgotten something. Your help is much appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to be able to sort a list, by either text or image (text) or both, or? It's a bit unclear...

Comment: Yes I want both text and image to be sorted. But what I have so far done successfully is the text being sorted excluded the image.

Comment: Ok, I suppose you should create a custom object to hold the different items for each row. So your custom object should hold an `int image, String house, String location, String price`. I'll try to write an answer a little later today, to illustrate how you can do it.

Comment: Added an answer now... hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here are an example of how to achieve your goal.

The best way is to create a custom object to hold the different strings and the image for each row.

This object could look like this:

```
public class MyCustomObject {
    private int image;
    private String house;
    private String location;
    private String price;

    public MyCustomObject(int image, String house, String location, String price) {
        this.image = image;
        this.house = house;
        this.location = location;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public String getHouse() {
        return house;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
}
```

Now to the `DBHelper` class. Instead of fetching one `String[]` for each type, you should fetch a `List` of `MyCustomObject`s. I choose `List` instead of arrays because these are easier to handle and should (in most cases) be used instead of the more primitive array. :-)

The `DBHelper.sortLocationAsc()` is renamed to `getAllMyCustomObjects()` instead and could look something like this:

```
public List<MyCustomObject> getAllMyCustomObjects() {
    Cursor localCursor = this.myDataBase.query(DB_TABLE, new String[] {
            KEY_ID, KEY_HOUSE, KEY_PRICE, KEY_LOCATION }, null, null,
            null, null, KEY_LOCATION + " ASC");

    String house = "";
    String price = "";
    String location = "";
    int image = 0;

    List<MyCustomObject> listOfObjects = new ArrayList<MyCustomObject>();
    while (localCursor.moveToNext()) {
        house = localCursor.getString(localCursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_HOUSAE));
        price = localCursor.getString(localCursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_PRICE));
        location = localCursor.getString(localCursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_LOCATION));
        image = localCursor.getInt(localCursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_IMAGE));

        listOfObjects.add(new MyCustomObject(image, house, location, price));
    }
    return listOfObjects;
}
```

Now when creating your custom `Adapter` I've changed it a bit, so it only takes a `List` of `MyCustomObject`s instead of the arrays.

You'll notice in the `getView` method that I fetch **one** item from the `List` of `MyCustomObject`s instead of fetching from each different array. This way it's much easier to control what elements belong together and you won't get weird behaviours like you could get if the different arrays aren't the same length.

The new `MyCustomAdapter` could look something like this:

```
class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    List<MyCustomObject> myListOfCustomObjects;

    MyCustomAdapter(List<MyCustomObject> customObjects) {
        this.myListOfCustomObjects = customObjects;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return myListOfCustomObjects.size();
    }

    public String getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View row;

        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow, null);

        textview1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        textview2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvLocation);
        textview3 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
        ImageView imageview = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image);

        imageview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        textview1.setText(myListOfCustomObjects.get(position).getHouse());
        Spanned strFormattedLocation = Html.fromHtml("<b>Location: </b>");
        Spanned strFormattedPrice = Html.fromHtml("<b>Price: </b>");
        textview2.setText(strFormattedLocation + myListOfCustomObjects.get(position).getLocation());
        String strPrice = strFormattedPrice
            + "$"
            + (new DecimalFormat("#,###.00")).format(Integer.parseInt(myListOfCustomObjects.get(position).getPrice()));
        textview3.setText(strPrice);
        imageview.setImageResource(myListOfCustomObjects.get(position).getImage());

        return row;
    }
}
```

And then you'll set the adapter in your `displayRecords()` like this:

```
private void displayRecords() {
    checkDatabaseConnection();
    List<MyCustomObject> list = dbHelper.getAllMyCustomObjects();
    adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(list);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

So the key is to create a custom object to hold the data.

The above code might not run/compile - I've just written it inside a text-editor and didn't test it at all, but now you hopefully have a clear view of how the issue can be solved :-)

Also: if you have a lot of data in your database, I'd recommend you looked into populating the `ListView` inside a background thread - for instance you could use an `[AsycnTask][1]` to do this.

Also have a look at the [`ViewHolder`](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) pattern when calling the `getView` of the `Adapter`.